# Why is my state counter one value behind what it should be?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state, setstate

Im new to reactjs. Im trying to create a comment section for some uploaded files, and keeping a counter on the comment buttons attached to each file. However, the counter is returning strange values. 
 Here is the relevent code:

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {


        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.clicked = false 
            this.commentButtonRef = React.createRef();
            this.state = {clickCounter:0, counterMat:[]} 
        }




         handleClick = () =>{


                console.log(this.state.clickCounter) 
                this.clicked = true;
                this.counterMat = []
                this.props.onCommentButtonClick(this.props.file, this.clicked)
                this.clicked = false;

            //update click counter
            this.setState({clickCounter:this.state.clickCounter + 1}, this.updateCounterMatrix())

        }

        updateCounterMatrix = ()=> {

                const temp = this.state.counterMat.slice() //copy the array
                temp[1] = this.state.clickCounter //execute the manipulations
                this.setState({counterMat: temp},console.log(this.state.counterMat, this.state.clickCounter))
            }

        createCounterMat=(element)=>{
            // use ref callback to pass DOM element into setState
            this.setState({counterMat:[element,this.state.clickCounter]}) 
            console.log(this.counterMat) 
        }

        render(){

            return( 

                <div className="item">
                        <i className="large file alternate icon"></i>
                        <div className="content">
                                <div className="header">{this.props.file}</div>
                                <button className='comment-button' 
                                        id = {this.props.file} 
                                        onClick = {this.handleClick} 
                                        key = {this.props.file}
                                        ref = {this.createCounterMat}
                                        clickcounter = {this.state.clickCounter}
                                > Comment</button> 
                        </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
}
```

Here are the issues im having:

1) As soon as this page first renders, my use of a reactRef callback function `createCounterMat` in the `button` element should console log's undefined, which is unexpected.

2) On the first click of my button, the `handleClick` function calls correctly. However, the console log's inside both `handleClick` and `updateCounterMatrix` both return a value of 0 for `this.state.clickCounter`. I expected the first to be 0, but the second `console.log` to be 1 by this stage.

3) On the second click, the `clickCounter` state seems to correctly increment by 1. However, the `console.log(this.state.counterMat, this.state.clickCounter)` gives a value of 0 inside `this.state.counterMat`, and a value of 1 in the case of simply this.state.clickCounter.

Here is a screenshot showing all of this [image: console logs]

Can anyone help me work out what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling console.log before the set state, not after. This:

```
 this.setState(
  {counterMat: temp},
  console.log(this.state.counterMat, this.state.clickCounter)
)
```

... means "call `console.log`, then pass its result along with `{counterMat: temp}` into `this.setState`". You probably meant to do:

```
 this.setState(
  {counterMat: temp},
  () => console.log(this.state.counterMat, this.state.clickCounter)
)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I've altered it as you said. I also realised i needed to do change   ```//update click counter
            this.setState({clickCounter:this.state.clickCounter + 1}, this.updateCounterMatrix())```   to   ```//update click counter
    this.setState({clickCounter:this.state.clickCounter + 1}, ()=>this.updateCounterMatrix())```   to fully solve the problem. However, im still getting undefined values on the first render

Comment: You're sometimes using `this.counterMat`, and sometimes `this.state.counterMat`. The log in createCountermat uses `this.counterMat`, but that variable doesn't get set until a click happens. If using two variables is unintentional, then update your code to just use one. If it's intentional, then give `this.counterMat` an initial value, probably in the constructor.